# How to get layout name in Nuxt 3 composition api <script setup>?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

In the docs, it only has setting layout, but nothing about getting the layout.

The code would look like this, but how do I get the value of `layout`

```
<div :class="`${layout === 'fluid' ? 'container-fluid' : 'container'}`">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div :class="`${$route.meta.layout === 'fluid' ? 'container-fluid' : 'container'}`">
</div>
```

and to access it in `<script setup></script>`

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'fluid',
})

const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.meta.layout)
</script>
```

Answered here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20281#discussioncomment-5618827